# Проверка trade offer link

Tags: php, javascript, регулярные-выражения

Пытаюсь проверить правильность steam trade offer link которая имеет вид

```
https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=200396688&token=XSvAH09r
```

(в данном случае это моя сылка)
Проверка на js и php, на js пробую так:

```
var expr = new RegExp(/http(?:s)://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=([0-9]+)&token=([a-zA-Z]+)/; 
expr.test("https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=200396688&token=XSvAH09r");
```

но пишет

```
SyntaxError: nothing to repeat
```

P.s кому не сложно, помогите ещё составить регулярное выражение на php, у меня с ними туго

Comment: У вас по-моему нет завершающей круглой скобки в выражении new RegExp(...

Comment: добавил, тоже самое..

Comment: Экранирования спец-символов не хватает еще, добавил ответ ниже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует поправить регулярное выражение следующим образом

```
  var expr = /http(?:s):\/\/steamcommunity.com\/tradeoffer\/new\/\?partner=([0-9]+)&token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/; 
  expr.test("https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=200396688&token=XSvAH09r");
```

На PHP

```
<?php
  $pattern = "/^http[s]*:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/tradeoffer\/new\/\?partner=([0-9]+)&token=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$/";
  $url = "https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=200396688&token=XSvAH09r";
  if(preg_match($pattern, $url)) echo "Валиден";
```

Comment: За php спасибо тоже))